# In the chromium source code, why some boundary or type checks use DCHECK

Tags: chromium, v8, embedded-v8

Recently, I was studying chromium and v8 source code, and saw a lot of `CHECK` or `DCHECK`. Among them, many `DCHECK` are checks on parameter types, or bounds on arrays, and `DCHECK` are closed in the release version.

```cpp
DCHECK(key->IsName() || key->IsNumber());    // Check for types
DCHECK(desc->is_empty());                    // Check for borderline conditions
```

Shouldn't it be better to use CHECK for boundary or type checks, which is still working in the release version? Or when choosing to use `DCHECK` or `CHECK`, are there any criteria? Because sometimes, the check that should be kept uses `DCHECK`

it confuses me alot, i don't know  whether DCHECK or CHECK should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `CHECK` and `DCHECK` cause a crash when they fail, so they're not intended or suitable for handling situations that are expected to happen. Instead, they're meant to "double-check" or document invariants that are assumed to be guaranteed to be true. That's why most of the time, it's enough to execute these checks in Debug mode, to keep Release-mode binaries smaller and faster. Using Release-mode `CHECK`s is a rare exception: it mostly serves as an additional layer of defense in complicated code that has had security bugs before. If a `CHECK` (or `DCHECK`) is hit in practice, then that's always a bug that should be fixed as soon as it's found.

The typical pattern is something like:

```
  if (!condition_holds()) {
    throw_error();
    return;
  }
  helper_function();
  ...

void helper_function() {
  DCHECK(condition_holds());  // Callers have checked, no need to check again.
  ...
}
```